# SharePoint 2013: Using StratusForms I deleted "NewForm.aspx", now only the new "NewForm" will not work

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Tools: SharePoint 2013, SharePoint 2013 Designer, StratusForms

What I was doing: StratusForms - Modify SharePoint's Default Forms with HTML Templates (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oai-m_KyzMc)

Status: DispForm and EditForm currently work, NewForm did work until the incident.

Incident: I deleted the main webpart on NewForm and the form was hosed, so I deleted NewForm.aspx. I recreated the NewForm.aspx and also added it to forms library (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108467/accidentally-deleted-default-editform-aspx). Like before when it worked, I added a Content Editor webpart and pointed it to my StratusForms template, but it did not work . The controls/boxes did not show up. It worked before on the old NewForm, and it currently works on DispForm & EditForm.

Question: Given the above information does anyone know why, or better yet have a solution, to get NewForm.aspx working with StratusForms again?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

So the underlying issue was SharePoints internal linkage of it's 3 forms (DispForm, EditForm, NewForm) to the data sources.

So those out-of-the-box forms are not like the ones we create. Even though you create a new "NewForm" and it may look like the old default NewForm, but it is not. There is metadata like Microsoft.SharePoint.PAGETYPE, which tells if it is a custom form or new, display, or edit form.

The resolution was found in this article (http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2011/03/11/troubleshooting-issues-with-dispform-editform-and-newform.aspx).

In case the link breaks I have also included the manual method here:

Manually

1. It's easiest if you take a corresponding form from another SharePoint List in the site and export it (SharePoint Designer) or just copy it to a text editor. This way, most of the settings of the List Form Web Part are already correct
2. Generate a new GUID and fill that in for the __WebPartId [uppercase & just change a few chars/numbers] and  properties  [lowercase, same as WebPartID & has a g_ prefix] of the List Form Web Part markup. It has to be the same GUID but the formatting is different. See the above screens for samples
3. Update the  property with the List ID you're targeting
4. Verify all other properties of the List Form Web Part and save the file as either DispForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx or NewForm.aspx
5. Import (SharePoint Designer) the page (or paste contents from the text editor)